# Joining two data frames that appear to be same type gives error 'ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns'

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames, sessions1 and sessions2 that I would like to join on field 'ga:dimension1'.

```
sessions1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 15775 entries, 0 to 15774
Data columns (total 9 columns):
ga:dimension1                15775 non-null object
ga:date                      15775 non-null object
ga:deviceCategory            15775 non-null object
ga:landingPagePath           15775 non-null object
ga:userType                  15775 non-null object
ga:operatingSystem           15775 non-null object
ga:operatingSystemVersion    15775 non-null object
ga:sessions                  15775 non-null int64
ga:bounces                   15775 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2), object(7)
memory usage: 1.1+ MB
sessions2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 15774 entries, 0 to 15773
Data columns (total 9 columns):
ga:dimension1         15774 non-null object
ga:source             15774 non-null object
ga:medium             15774 non-null object
ga:campaign           15774 non-null object
ga:adContent          15774 non-null object
ga:keyword            15774 non-null object
ga:channelGrouping    15774 non-null object
ga:sessions           15774 non-null int64
ga:bounces            15774 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2), object(7)
memory usage: 1.1+ MB
```

Looking at the first few rows they look the same at least:

```
sessions1.head()
            ga:dimension1   ga:date  ... ga:sessions ga:bounces
0  1567331564026.evxjzuot  20190901  ...           1          1
1  1567331572999.vtnsczsj  20190901  ...           1          1
2  1567331693070.fkdbmcj6  20190901  ...           1          1
3  1567335919816.ctz12xcl  20190901  ...           1          0
4  1567345181556.b3yowmbh  20190901  ...           1          1

sessions2.head()
            ga:dimension1 ga:source  ... ga:sessions ga:bounces
0  1567331564026.evxjzuot  (direct)  ...           1          1
1  1567331572999.vtnsczsj  (direct)  ...           1          1
2  1567331693070.fkdbmcj6  (direct)  ...           1          1
3  1567335919816.ctz12xcl  (direct)  ...           1          0
4  1567345181556.b3yowmbh  (direct)  ...           1          1
```

However, when I try this:

```
sessions_combined = sessions1.join(sessions2,
                                   on = 'ga:dimension1',
                                   how = 'left')
```

I get an error message:

> ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If
>   you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Why is this and how should I join the two data frames together?

Comment: You need to use `merge` and not `join`.   Join is trying to join the index of session1 to the column `ga:dimension1` of session2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `merge`

```
sessions_combined = sessions1.merge(sessions2,
                                   on = 'ga:dimension1',
                                   how = 'left')
```